# What are these commands for?

Tags: linux, mount, grub2

Yesterday I had to install a Windows with its Grub override.

Well, it's not the first time I had to fix Grub, so I used LiveCD, mounted the root partition (I don't have boot, just `/` and `home`) and ran `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`. However, it didn't work.

After Googling a while I found a tutorial in which instead of just mounting the Linux partition, he also did `mount --bind /mnt/dev /dev` and `mount --bind /mnt/proc /proc/`. After that `chroot` to `/mnt` and then installed Grub, and using this method, it worked.

What are the `mount --bind` commands for? I'm familiar with the usage of `--bind used` (man page) but I do not know why it was used on this example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`proc` and `sys` filesystems are provided by the running kernel -- when the kernel is not running, they cease to exist. This means that when you chroot into another operating system, these filesystems are not present. Many programs expect them to exist so that they can function, for example, they may require information about the running system, or want to modify the way the kernel handles something. It is often enough simply to provide `/proc` and `/sys` from the current kernel for these programs to work as expected.

A symlink would not suffice, as the act of chrooting would invalidate the file paths used. In Linux, you also cannot hard link directories (other than `.` and `..`, as provided by `mkdir`). This means that a third option has to be used to mirror these filesystems to the chrooted environment -- bind mounting. A bind mount is provided by the kernel directly, and works as expected within a chroot.

Comment: `proc` and `sys` can be mounted in multiple places so `--bind` is not needed (only mount them twice). However `/dev/` is managed by udev not insider kernel.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I never mentioned /dev, because it's not in the question, but that doesn't have to be managed by udev necessarily.

Comment: I was more referring to `proc` and `sys` as filesystems which can be double-mounted (`mount -t proc none /mnt/proc`) so you don't necessary need to `mount --bind` them. `dev` is usually managed by userspace (be it udev, busybox or anything else) so you need to do it. Minor point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `--bind` option will allow the mount point to show up in a `chroot`-ed enviroment.